# Boostrap minimum scale with rotativa PDF

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, pdf, rotativa

I have a problem when using rotativa, that my bootstrap page always scales to minimum when printed. Is there any way I can set viewport size for my view, so it wont scale bootstrap to minimum for PDF generation?

Controller implementation

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DownloadViewPDF()
{
    var vm = new Viewmodel();
    return new Rotativa.ViewAsPdf("SummaryPDF", vm) { FileName = "TestViewAsPdf.pdf", PageSize = Size.A4 };
}
```

And this is my general view implementation

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <span class="label">Email</span>
            <span class="form-control-static">test@email.com</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="required-enabled">
                <span class="label">Phone</span>
                <span class="form-control-static">(804) 222-1111</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried a few things, for an example using the PageSize, PageHeight, PageWidth settings of rotativa. Nothings seems to prevent the scaling. I've also tried using CustomSwitches, but couldnt really find a setting that provided the result I wanted.

I've also tried setting a static viewport size in the html meta tag, and encapsulating my view in a div with static width. None of these things seem to prevent my PDF from being scaled to minimum possible bootstrap display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution ended up being putting all our responsive design into tables, thus trashing the responsive design for the print part. There seemed to be no other way that I could find. It would be nice with a feature to just specify viewport size for the print.

Answer (score 3):

I use "--viewport-size" switch

```cs
new ViewAsPdf("Edit", model) { PageOrientation = Orientation.Landscape, CustomSwitches = "--viewport-size 1000x1000" };
```

Comment: This is by far the best answer here.  I tried it and it works great without having to modify my page from the standard view.  I set mine to: 1920x1080.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else still stumbling across this: More than three years later, there is no definitive answer for this issue using bootstrap. A legacy table-based implementation still seems to be the best workaround.

Even the underlying `Wkhtmltopdf` library's latest version (0.12.5.0 stable) does not play well with the columns, nor with the new Bootstrap 4 that's now out in the wild. Users are still trying the hack-y Viewport workaround, with varying rates of success:
https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2301

Some users indicate that switching to `col-xs-*` as suggested here does the trick. Others, myself included, have no luck with that approach. Even setting a `max-width` attribute on the column keeps the columns sized properly, but they don't "line up" horizontally as they should.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to change all `col-md` and `col-sm` into `col-xs`.
That should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

you need to change `col-sm-*` to `col-xs-*`